# how to export folder specific environment variables?

Tags: command-line, java, environment-variables

I have two projects on my computer that require JAVA_HOME to point to jdk7 and 8 respectively.

Right now I'm working around this by having 2 files in my home folder that i source to set JAVA_HOME correctly whenever I move to the root folder of one of these folders.

Is there a way I can tie the sourcing of these files to the action of "cd"ing to the root of these projects?

Comment: To start the jar/class file in this folders or to develop the projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the bash shell, add to your .bash_profile:

```
mycd(){
        builtin cd "$@"
        case $PWD in
        */proj1*)  export JAVA_HOME=/a ;;
        */proj2*)  export JAVA_HOME=/b ;;
        esac
}
alias cd=mycd
```

Then when you type `cd ...` it will run `mycd` in which you can do stuff.
It starts by calling the real built-in cd.

You need to start a new interactive bash to see the effect, of course.